# How to check if no PDF is displayed in an implementation of 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1' Java library

Tags: java, android, androidpdfviewer

I am using [this PDF Library](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer) in my application at the latest version.

I have a `PDFView` object declared in this way:

```
PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
```

And I would like to check whether if it is currently displaying/containing a PDF.

I did this:

```
if(pdfView.getPageCount() == 0){
   ...
}
```

which works, but I'd like something like [this line](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer/blob/d243b39377f19c3eae41e227067da254ebbf731b/android-pdf-viewer/src/main/java/com/github/barteksc/pdfviewer/PDFView.java#L289) in the library's source code. Sadly we cannot access `pdfFile` from outside, nor is given to us something like `isEmpty()` or `isNull()`.

Is there a way to see if the inner pdf is null or not? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This's my suggestion

I don't know if library have a method you want, but when you open pdfFile, you can check it or do another things in onError , it look like this:

```
    pdfView.fromUri(fileUri)...
           .onError{
               //you can finish or send a message here
           }
```